# How can I vary the number of activities based on user input?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to coding on android. I'm creating a flashcard application. I want to allow the user to add as many words as they want, but doing so would mean the structure of the activity would have to change at runtime, or I would need to create a new activity at runtime. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use activities for this. You can store the words in say `List` and display the contents of the using a `Recyclerview` or a `ViewPager`